# After concatenation print new line in SQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql

**Greeting to all smart people around here !**

I'm using **concat to retrieving two columns into a single column**. Here is my query.

```
select 
    concat(booking_startdate, ' ', booking_starttime) as date 
from 
    family_resources_booking_tbl;
```

This is working fine. After concatenation I just wanted to **print booking_starttime into a new line**. Is there any way to do that??

Answer (score 2):

You can put a carriage return in your string:

```
select 
    concat(booking_startdate, ' 
', booking_starttime) as date 
from 
    family_resources_booking_tbl;
```

There might be some circumstances where that won't work.  You can use the `CHAR()` function to insert carriage return (13) and/or line feed (10):

```
select concat(booking_startdate, CHAR(13), booking_starttime) as date 
from 
    family_resources_booking_tbl;
```

Answer (score 0):

you  can achive it like this also

```
     SELECT
     booking_startdate + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + booking_starttime AS Date
     FROM
     family_resources_booking_tbl;
```